# Pass data between mvc methods

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, methods

```
string jsonoutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportDefenitionJson);
```

How do I pass data from one method to another while returning Json to a view?  Here's and example of what I mean:

```
public JsonResult SubmitReport(string JsonStringSend, Guid ReportId)
{
    dynamic JSend = JObject.Parse(JsonStringSend);
    var schema = JsonSchema4.FromType<ReportItem>();
    var schemaData = schema.ToJson();
    var errors = schema.Validate(JSend.JsonString);
    schema = JsonSchema4.FromJson(schemaData);
    Guid ReportID = Guid.NewGuid();
    Guid GetUserID = Guid.NewGuid();
    DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    string ReportCreator = GetUserID.ToString() + " : " + CurrentDateTime.ToString();
    JObject Report = (JObject)JSend["JsonString"];
    Report["ReportID"] = ReportID.ToString();
    Report["CreatedBy"] = ReportCreator;
    string ReportDefenitionJson = Report.ToString();
    string ReportIdJsonFileName = ReportID.ToString() + ".json";
    this.StoreReportDefenition(ReportDefenitionJson, ReportIdJsonFileName);

    List<ReturnJsonErrors> ReturnJson = new List<ReturnJsonErrors>();
    ReturnJson.Add(new ReturnJsonErrors { Success = true, Errors = null });

    return Json(ReturnJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void StoreReportDefenition(string ReportDefenitionJson, string ReportIdJsonFileName)
{
     string jsonoutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportDefenitionJson);
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonoutput);
     MemoryStream fileContents = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     var fullAddress = string.Format("11a5/Reporting/Reports/Report/{0}", ReportDefenitionJson);
     AmazonS3Repository repo = new AmazonS3Repository(InRollPlus.Shared.ConstantVals.ConstantItem.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, InRollPlus.Shared.ConstantVals.ConstantItem.AWS_SECRET_KEY);
     repo.PutFile(fileContents, fullAddress, null, "data.json", false);
}
```

How do I pass `ReportDefenitionJson` and `ReportIdJsonFileName` to the method `StoreReportDefenition` while still returning Json to the view?

Comment: What's wrong with `this.StoreReportDefenition(ReportDefenitionJson, ReportIdJsonFileName)` before returning the JsonResult? What does the method do?

Comment: Will that execute StoreReportDefenition?  Or do I need to add an execute method within StoreReportDefenition?

Comment: `StoreReportDefenition` is just an instance method that doesn't return anything. You don't provide any code for that so no one can guess what it does. Have you tried this with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `this.StoreReportDefenition(ReportDefenitionJson, ReportIdJsonFileName);` Will pass the data and execute the method perfectly.